# Python Typing Annotation inside __init__

Tags: python, typing

How to annotate the type of an instance variable that is only avaiable after `__init__`? I'd like to list all instance attributes inside `__init__` as per [POLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

MWE:

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.foo :Union[CustomClass, None] = None

   def set_foo(self):
      self.foo = CustomClass()

   def use_foo(self):
      self.foo.do_something()
```

Inside `__init__`, if I just annotate foo as `self.foo: CustomClass = None`, Pylint will complain:

> T484: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type None, variable has type "CustomClass").

However, if I annotate `foo` as `self.foo: Union[CustomClass, None] = None` (as in above MWE), PyLint will then complain inside `use_foo` function:

> T484: "None" has no attribute "do_something".

How do I make PyLint happy? (w/o disabling T484)

Comment: Just ignore it. Let tools help you but not dominate you.

Comment: @Sraw I respectfully disagree. Said tool is highlighting an unhandled potential bug in the application. I think OP is doing the right thing by understanding this error more and learning how to deal with it properly.

Comment: Yes tool is telling you there is a **potential** bug. Notice it is a **potential** bug. If you realize this is not a bug but is exactly what you design. Why do you have to "fix" it? Honestly as Python is a dynamic language, this situation cannot be avoided completely.

Comment: @Sraw I can not tell you how many times PyLint saves my day by spotting some subtle bugs (esp. with typing). So I prefer to let it continue provide high quality signal. In this case, I think PyLint is raising a legit issue. Just want to figure out the "right" and "graceful" way to handle it instead of ignoring the warnings.

Comment: I'm not saying you should disable `PyLint` or something else. I mean, `PyLint` should make you happy instead of you make `PyLint` happy. This **is** a legit warning but it shouldn't beyond your design. Or maybe I realize the point. As for me, I already know it is not easy to overcome this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to simply initialise `self.foo` to `""` instead of `None`.

This means that `self.foo.upper()` will be available, so pylint will have no cause to complain.

If you don't want `use_foo` to be useable until `get_foo` (which probably would be better called `set_foo`) is called, you could check to make sure that `self.foo` is populated, or keep a boolean field stating whether it has ever been run.

---

If your class is a little more complicated than a string, you'll have to do a quick check before using `self.foo`.

```
def use_foo(self):
    if self.foo is None:
        raise EnvironmentError("You haven't called get_foo!")
    self.foo.upper()
```

This is not a very clean solution - I think we can do better.

Lets try outsourcing this check to a decorator;

```
def ensure_foo(func):
    def inner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.foo is None:
            raise EnvironmentError("You haven't called get_foo!")
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner_func
```

I haven't personally tried this with pylint - but if pylint is clever enough to work out what's going on, slapping `@ensure_foo` on top of your class methods is going to be a lot cleaner than putting None checks everywhere...

Comment: I'm using str as a dummy example here. My actual type of `foo` is a custom class type that does not have a easy default.

I have addtional checks to make sure `self.foo` is not used until it's set. But PyLint seems do not know that..

Comment: Ah. In that case, what happens if you do an explicit None check at the start of `use_foo`? Pylint might be smart enough to realise you've filtered out the potential of that situation...

Comment: Yes! confirmed that if I do:
if self.foo:
   self.foo.do_something()

Then PyLint is happy. But I have do this every time I access `self.foo`, which is a huge pain...

Comment: The only way around that I'm afraid will be to rearchitect your class so that it doesn't have a situation where it can be null. You might be able to neaten it up by using a decorator though. I'll add my last comment to the answer.

Comment: the ensure_foo decorator is nice. But I have a bunch of such "foo"s and a bunch of functions that use them. I'm afraid the decorators will quickly become un-manageable as well. I agree that I don't see any clean way to handle this situation either. Accepting for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries :) If it's that big a problem, you may want to rethink your design a bit though. If you can manage to know foo at initialisation time, having it as an argument to `__init__` is going to be a much cleaner solution than anything else.